# Trying to find all instances for a certain Text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find all instances of a certain text within a range. I tried to creating a "Do Loop", but my loop keeps running, and doesn't time out.

```
Dim TextRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Dim Cables As Range

LastRow = Report.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set TextRange = rReport.Range("A20:AE" & RangeLastRow)

Set Cables = Report.Range("G20:G" & LastRow)
    
Dim cel As Range

Set cel = Cables.Cells.Find(what:=CableNumber)

If Not FindNumber Is Nothing Then 'If the number is found
    Debug.Print CableNumber
    Debug.Print FindCableNumber.Address

    Do
        Set FindNumber = Cables.FindNext(FindNumber)
    Loop While Not FindNumber Is Nothing
    
Else    'If the cable number is not found
End If
```

Comment: `FindNumber ` is not even declared and you check it if `Is Nothing`. How to even reach the loop being nothing? Please, try replacing `Set cel =` with `Set FindNumber =`. Of course, if this is what are you looking for. Then, where `FindNumber` does receive any value? Please, add on top of the module `Option Explicit`. This will not let you using not declared variables and avoid a lot of potential confusions...

Comment: You do not show us the whole code and it is difficult to understand what you try accomplishing. Anyhow the way of exiting the Loop is wrong. `FindNumber` will never be nothing if a first match exists.

Answer (score 0):

The code you show is not complete and I am trying to deduce what you try accomplishing. I commented the strange lines, and changed the variables in a way to make it working. But I cannot be sure that what I suppose you really want accomplishing. Anyhow, please try understanding the next adapted code, test the suggested way and send some feedback:

```
Sub FandAllOccurrencesInRange()
 Dim TextRange As Range 'not used
 Dim LastRow As Long

 Dim Cables As Range, Report As Worksheet, CableNumber
 Set Report = Worksheets("Report") 'in case that Report is not the sheet code name
 LastRow = Report.Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
 
 'Set TextRange = rReport.Range("A20:AE" & RangeLastRow) 'not used
 'is rReport a typo, or another undeclared, un set sheet?
 Set Cables = Report.Range("G20:G" & LastRow)
 
 CableNumber = "something" 'you must give a value to the variable to be searched!!!
 
 Dim FindNumber As Range, firstAddress As String
 Set FindNumber = Cables.Find(what:=CableNumber)
 If Not FindNumber Is Nothing Then 'If the number is found
    firstAddress = FindNumber.Address
    Debug.Print CableNumber
    Debug.Print FindCableNumber.Address

    Do
        Debug.Print FindNumber.Address
        Set FindNumber = Cables.FindNext(FindNumber)
    Loop While FindNumber.Address <> firstAddress
    
 Else    'If the cable number is not found
 End If
End Sub
```

It is good to know that  `FindNext` returns in a loop, restarting iteration from the first occurrences. That's why `firstAddress` is necessary.